# Android MVP - How to create Model/Repository instance in background service to access model method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp

I am using MVP pattern in My Android application. My requirement is

**1. Sync captured data when user clicks 'Sync' button**

**2. Job-scheduler who will invoke the background service at midnight and sync data with server even though the app is not running.**

The flow for both scenarios is:

**1)Sync captured data when user clicks 'Sync' button**

- getPresenter().notifySyncBtnPressed() will be called
- notifySyncBtnPressed() will instruct the Model by calling mModel.sync()
- Sync from Model has entire implementation of fetching data from DB, upload it to server and notify result to Presenter
- Presenter then notify to View by calling getView().notifySyncFinished()

**Note: This flow is clear to me - suggest improvements if needed**

**2) Job-scheduler who will invoke the background service( Please provide your clarification here)**

- BroadcastReceiver will invoke Service class which extends IntentService
- Create model object (IModel model = new Model()) and call model.sync() from onHandleIntent().
- Since there is no UI, no need to invoke presenter. and no need to notify the status.
- Service will get killed once sync operation is done.

Please suggest,

**1. is it the right way to call Model (Repository) instance from Service class?**

**2. I am also confuse between Model layer and Repositiry layer, is there any difference in Model layer and Repository layer here in MVP.**

Comment: hum, you get the on click in the activity, the activity call syncWithServer in the presenter, then the presenter can call a method on your activity that can communicate with the service. why do you want the presenter instance from the service?

Comment: Requirement is: Application should sync with server on every 4 hours even though app is not running, User should be able to sync with server manually also on sync btn click.To achieve this, I am using alarmManager to schedule a task in every 4 hours where background service should launch which will sync the data with the server and notify user via notification in notification bar.

Comment: the presenter handles the view, if the operation has to be triggered without any UI, what do you need the presenter for?

Comment: As per phase 1 implementation, Entire business logic is in Presenter and Sync operation is triggering on button click. now in phase 2, sync should trigger on certain intervals. (may be using JobScheduler or alarmManager)
So bit confused in terms of designing/ redesigning the app.

Comment: I can see your confusion, keep in mind that the purpose of a presenter is to control the UI, think of it as a puppeteer. if need to perform a task that needs no UI and you still need the presenter, there is something wrong with the design

Comment: Please provide your view on this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see why you want the presenter from the Service, if this is the case, I think you should create a Presenter specifically for the Service. It's pretty hardcore but it would makes sense.

Anyway the steps seems fine, the presenter should interact with the "Model" (the M in MVP) and it's usually composed by interactors. If you want to use repository pattern, that would happen behind the interactors and would be part of the Model layer.

I would rename your IModel to IInteractor and every component that needs data will interface with that class. The repositories are accessed then by the Interactor and are not visible to the Presentation layer.